# wordpress doesnt add media.css file

Tags: media, wp-enqueue-style, css

I recognized that site is not responsive and media.css file is not working, i inspected with dev tools what kind of styles are included in header and i found that there is min version`/css/media.min.css?ver=4.8.1`, but i include media.css without min, What can be the problem that media.css is not working?

This is how i included my scripts and styles

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.min.js', array(), null,true);
    wp_register_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), null,true);
    wp_register_script('mixitup_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/mixitup.min.js', array(), null,true);
    wp_register_script('fancybox_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.js', array(), null,true);
    wp_register_script('main_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js', array(), null,true);

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js');
    wp_enqueue_script('main_js');

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('media', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/media.css');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

`/css/media.min.css?ver=4.8.1` is not indicative of a "min version". The filename of this CSS file is LITERALLY: 'media.min.css'. (Additionally the file is versioned with the `ver` parameter set to `4.8.1`).

So atetmpting to enqueue:

```
wp_enqueue_style('media', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/media.css');
```

Will certainly fail, and should in fact be:

```
wp_enqueue_style('media', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/media.min.css');
```

Comment: and file should be as well renamed to media.min.css?

Comment: If it is not, then (according to dev tools) you have something else including (not sure if successfully) a file called media.min.css

Comment: i have file named media.css by not media.min.css

Comment: There must still be a path based problem though, so firstly do a site wide search for "/css/media.min" in your IDE to find out where this minned file is being included

Answer (score 0):

You Forget to add `.min.` `wp_enqueue_style('media', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/media.min.css');`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I changed the handle name from media to `mediaa`, and it worked.

```
wp_enqueue_style('media', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/media.css');
```

to

```
wp_enqueue_style('mediaa', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/media.css');
```